# firebase auth/unauthorized-domain error although I authorized the domain

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I tried to set up Firebase Authentication and on localhost it worked too. But after I get the app on Firebase I get the error `auth/unauthorized-domain`.

I have already looked in Firebase and the domain is whitelisted.

My code to login to firebase using Google:

```
const provider = new auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then ( credential => {
      return this.updateUserData(credential.user);
    })
```

```js
private updateUserData(user) {
    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<User> = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);

    const data = {
      uid: user.uid,
      email: user.email,
      displayName: user.displayName,
      photoURL: user.photoURL
    };

    return userRef.set(data, { merge: true });
  }
```

Here is the full error message:

```
code: "auth/unauthorized-domain"
message: "This domain (nutrimap-c4d12.web.app) is not authorized to run this operation. Add it to the OAuth redirect domains list in the Firebase console -
```

Comment: If you think you've done everything correctly, but it's not working the way you expect, please contact Firebase support directly for troubleshooting assistance.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Thanks for the tip I'll try that.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that your domain **nutrimap-c4d12.web.app** is not added to the firebase OAuth redirect domains. You need to make sure that their domain is already present in **OAuth redirect domains**, by going to **SETUP SIGN IN METHOD** on the console **Auth** tab.

Comment: Nope, the domain is already added there. Under Authorized Domains if you ment that